# Google Big Query Invalid time zone: +0000

Tags: google-bigquery

Getting the error

```
Query Failed
Error: Invalid time zone: +0000
```

Is there a way to ignore time zones or default everything to UCT
This is my where condition

```
WHERE TIMESTAMP(FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E6S%z", PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y%m%d", date )),"UCT") = TIMESTAMP('2018-03-05 00:00',"UCT")
```

`date` column is string in this format 20180307

Answer (score 1):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer originally left by the question asker as a comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

The fix was removing the timestamp formatting from `FORMAT_TIMESTAMP`

```
TIMESTAMP(FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d", PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y%m%d", ga.date )))
```

Answer (score -1):

You're specifying `UCT`, an invalid time zone as it is a misspelling. The time zone you are looking for is `UTC`.

Incorrect:

```
... TIMESTAMP('2018-03-05 00:00',"UCT")
```

Correct:

```
... TIMESTAMP('2018-03-05 00:00',"UTC")
```

Comment: Both fail and both are supported https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Supported-Time-Zone-Values_66194188

Comment: Since it is a string, does your `date` column have any references to other time zones other than UCT, or is it purely an integer as you describe e.g. `20180307`? Is it uniformly 8 characters? It would be interesting to see if your format doesn't strictly adhere to this. I would search for your localized time zone. `SELECT date FROM project.dataset.table WHERE date LIKE '%servertimehere%'`

Comment: They are all length 8